# What is this font that was used in the 1930s for this school's yearbooks?

Tags: font-identification

"Latigo" is the name of the yearbook for Texas Country Day School, an all-boys prep school in Dallas that existed from 1933 to 1950.  It merged with another school in 1950 and became St. Mark's School of Texas, which still exists today.  This font was used for a number of years on the TCD yearbooks, this specific image is from the 1938 yearbook.  Was this simply a made-up font, or was there any historical context to it?  Thank you.[image: 1938 Latigo yearbook, Texas Country Day School, Dallas]

Comment: Well 1930s.. it wasn't a "font". Might have been movable type or press-on, but a "font", being a digital package, probably never existed. Someone may have created a font of the same typeface later though. Was it used throughout or merely as a "logo"? As a logo it may have merely been artwork.

Comment: Thank you for the reply -- it was used on the school's yearbooks from 1938 to 1941.  It may be merely artwork, but I am not sure, and I am just an amateur researcher, trying to see if there is some back-story to this style of lettering.