# Late 1940s "Latigo" yearbook font from Texas Country Day School

Tags: font-identification

This is the same school as [my earlier question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/154839/what-is-this-font-that-was-used-in-the-1930s-for-this-schools-yearbooks), Texas Country Day School, and they used this font on the covers of their yearbooks from 1945-1949.

[image: Texas Country Day School, 1945-49]

Comment: This is hand drawn. Look at the non-uniform serif sizes (on the T especially), and the sloppy asymmetric size and positioning of the barbs. You might see work like this today in a freeware font, but not in a commercial font. The number 1948 is also clearly hand drawn.

Comment: OK, thank you.  I had not thought of that since it was used for the 4-year period.  If you had to pick one font that it most closely resembled, could you suggest that?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: [Something like this, maybe?](https://www.dafont.com/texas-tango.font?text=LATIGO) I don't think you'll find anything very close, but try searching for fonts with keywords like "Cowboy", "Tex Mex" or "Wild West" and see what pops up.

Comment: Great, thank you very much.  The Texas Tango is very close other than the tiny serifs on top and on bottom of the letters from the yearbooks.

Comment: You were very helpful, thank you -- on this question.  I posed another question a few hours before this one about an unusual font from even earlier yearbooks for the same school.  Can you please review that image and give me your thoughts on that?  I appreciate it.

Comment: fonts like this often have "wood" in the name as they are inspired by or recreations of woodblock/woodcut typefaces. e.g. "Cottonwood"